# escaping = character in java string

Tags: java, struts

Iam formating my question. Sorry for this. Here is the summary of my question

in JSP I have a field

```
<input  maxlength="200" name="productName" >
```

I enter value like "`cQN==ujyRMdr+Qi8dO9Xm*eRun+ner==aLTyt?aKmGI`"

In Action

```
public String getXMLObject(HttpServletRequest request)  throws Exception
{
    URLDecoder decoder = new URLDecoder();
    String productName = decoder.decode(productLicenseKey ,"UTF-8");
    System.out.println("-->ProductNameAction---->getXMLObject--->productName -->  : "+productName);
}
```

Iam getting output as "`cQN==ujyRMdr Qi8dO9Xm*eRun ner==aLTyt?aKmGI`".
If you observe + is converting to space which I don't want.

If I won't use decoder.decode other characters are converting to the respective escape chars. But I want as it is in the Action class

---

code how iam  and retrieving value

in JSP I have a field

I enter value like "1012990-c1e197eda0s-a1de198b0b2-819e25307de-xnXrmXWBidhksyn70rGyTHa==cQNujyRMdrQi8dO9Xm+eRunERd==aLTyt+aKmGI+KRCcRtmP5ehfR=="
In Action

```
private String saveProductName( SWHttpServletRequest request)
             throws Exception

{
    try
    {
                String ProductName      = request.getParameter("ProductName");
                System.out.println("-->ProductAction---->saveProductName--->ProductName -->  : "+ProductName);  
    }
 }
```

Iam getting output as "1012990-c1e197eda0s-a1de198b0b2-819e25307de-xnXrmXWBidhksyn70rGyTHa%253D%253DcQNujyRMdrQi8dO9Xm+eRunERd%253D%253DaLTyt+aKmGI+KRCcRtmP5ehfR%253D%253D"
If we use decoder except + everything is working fine

Comment: I think it is related to URLEncoding, not HTMLEncoding. You may try URLEncoding.

Comment: How are you *retrieving* the parameters? I don't know why you're calling `escapeHtml` on it at this point.

Comment: First I tried using 

String productName= request.getParameter("productName");

When it is not working I used escapeHTML but still it is no use. If I use URLEncoder.encode, there is no problem for + sign but =is converting to %3D which should not.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it simple. Please excuse me

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to decode anything in the action. The servlet api does that for you. `request.getParameter()` is sufficient. The problem is that you didn't properly encode the parameter when generating the form field or URL.

If it's a form field, then it's part of HTML code, and thus must be HTML-escaped:

```
<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="<c:out value="${theFieldValue}"/>"/>
```

The struts html:hidden also takes care of html-escaping properly.

If it's a URL, then it should be url-encoded, and html-escaped:

```
<c:url var="theUrl" value="someUrl.do">
    <c:param name="someName" value="${theFieldValue}"/>
</c:url>
<a href="<c:out value="${theUrl}"/>">The link text</a>
```

If you type this value in a text field of a form, then `request.getParameter()` is sufficient.

Comment: Previously I used to use just request.getParameter() but it didnot worked. so used decoder. I just type the value in the text box and get the value in Action class using request.getParameter().

Comment: It should work without decoding anything. Try again, and show us the code of the action and the generated HTML code for the form.

Comment: JB Nizet, I have edited my question to include the code how Iam retriving

Comment: The input name is "productName" (lower-case p). The parameter you use to get its value is "ProductName" (upper-case P). You're not reading the content of the field. And what's the class SWHttpServletRequest? Where does it come from?

Comment: I changed the names not to reflect the original names of my code. while changing I missed the case sensitivity . Its productName. SWHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequest.

Comment: And what does it do? It's probably just this class that doesn't decode the parameters correctly. Where does it come from? Where's its source code? In what environment are you running the app? this class is not standard.